# Can a program ever receive a software interrupt?

Tags: software-rec, interrupt

Can a program ever receive a software interrupt? I understand that they can cause interrupts, but can they actually **recieve** a software interrupt? If so, please can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Wikipedia : "A software interrupt is caused either by an exceptional condition in the processor itself, or a special instruction in the instruction set which causes an interrupt when it is executed. The former is often called a trap or exception and is used for errors or events occurring during program execution that are exceptional enough that they cannot be handled within the program itself. [...] The operating system will catch this exception, and can choose to abort the instruction." If I understand correctly what you're asking, the answer would be no.